# Add MouseDown and MouseMove event on a class at runtime

Tags: c#, runtime, eventhandler

I try to add an event handler to a personnal class that inherit from the .NET class "Panel".

I tried some several ways to do it but it's not working anymore...

I have a Principal Panel that contains other Panel. It's to design Grafcet.

So I have my class "Etape" that inherit from Panel :

```
 class Etape : Panel
    {
        private Point MouseDownLocation;

        private void Etape_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
                this.BackColor = CouleurSelect;
                MessageBox.Show("Bonjour");
            }
        }

        private void Etape_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                this.Left = e.X + this.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
                this.Top = e.Y + this.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
            }
        }
    }
```

And I declare it like that :

```
 toto = new Etape();
 toto.BackColor = Color.White;
 toto.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
 toto.Width = 40;
 toto.Height = 40;
```

"toto" is add to my "principal" Panel just after that.
I would like to add an Eventhandler to move my panels at runtime. I tried the code you can see above, but I think C# doesn't detect that I'm clicking on the Etape.

Do you have an idea or something to help me ?

Julien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the OnMouseXXX methods:

```
class Etape : Panel
{
    private Point MouseDownLocation;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            this.BackColor = CouleurSelect;
            MessageBox.Show("Bonjour");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.Left = e.X + this.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
            this.Top = e.Y + this.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

Just declaring a method called `Etape_MouseMove()` doesn't hook anything up to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. That's what I needed !
I will remember that "Just declaring a method called Etape_MouseMove() doesn't hook anything up to it."

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook the functions to an event

```
class Etape : Panel
    {
        public Etape()
        {
            MouseDown += Etape_MouseDown;
            MouseMove += Etape_MouseMove;
        }

        private Point MouseDownLocation;

        private void Etape_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
                this.BackColor = CouleurSelect;
                MessageBox.Show("Bonjour");
            }
        }

        private void Etape_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                this.Left = e.X + this.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
                this.Top = e.Y + this.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
            }
        }
    }
```